# PHP / MySQL: Display some error after successfully updated the data

Tags: php, mysql

Currently, I create a system using CRUD function. I have some problems with my update function. The problem is, it will display the error at view_task.php like:

1) Undefined index: report_id at line 7
2) Undefined variable: task_name at line 50

The problem is, when I check the database, the data has been updated.

Below is my current code:

dashboard.php

```
   echo "<form method = 'post' action = 'view_task/view_task.php'>";
     echo "<input type = 'hidden' name = 'report_id' value = '".$report_id."'>";
     echo "<button type = 'submit' class='btn-primary'>View</button>";
   echo "</form>";
```

view_task.php

```
<?php

  require_once "../../../../config/configPDO.php";
  require_once "../../../../config/check.php";

  $report_id = $_POST['report_id']; //line 7

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM ot_report LEFT JOIN ot_users ON ot_report.badgeid = ot_users.badgeid LEFT JOIN ot_team ON ot_team.team_id = ot_users.team_id WHERE report_id = :report_id";
  $query = $conn->prepare($sql);
  $query->execute(array(':report_id' => $report_id));
  while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

      $report_id = $row["report_id"];
      $task_name = $row["task_name"];

  }

?>

<form action="update_task_name.php" method="POST">
  <td><b>Task Name</b></td>
  <td colspan = '2'><input type="text" class="form-control" name="task_name" value="<?php echo $task_name; ?>"/></td> //line 50
  <input type="hidden" name="report_id" value="<?php echo $report_id ?>"> 
  <td><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value = "Save" onclick="confirm('Are you sure?')"></td>
</form>
```

update_task_name.php

```
<?php

    require_once '../../../../config/configPDO.php';

    $update = "UPDATE ot_report SET task_name = :task_name WHERE report_id = :report_id";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($update);
    $stmt->bindParam(':task_name', $_POST['task_name']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':report_id', $_POST['report_id']);
    $stmt->execute();

    class Result {}
    $response = new Result();
    $response->result = 'OK';
    $response->message = 'Update successful';
    header("Location: view_task.php");

?>
```

Can anyone help me to fix this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the view_task.php page the $ _POST ['report_id'] section is not defined after the data update, because in update_task_name.php you use a redirect header ("Location: view_task.php") which becomes the GET method

try to update

update_task_name.php

```
header ("Location: view_task.php?report_id=". $ _ POST ['report_id'])
```

view_task.php //line 7

```
if (isset ($_POST['report_id'])) {
    $report_id = $_POST['report_id'];
} else if (isset ($_GET['report_id'])) {
    $report_id = $_GET['report_id'];
} else {
    die ("ID NOT DEFINED");
}
```

Comment: This is the correct one. Thanks bro

Comment: glad to help @PeterSondak

Comment: wait bro. the answer seems correct, but after updated, the i pressed back button at browser, it will display 'Confirm Form Resubmission'. Then, Ineed to press again back button to go to the dashboard.php. Can u know why ?

Comment: maybe it's because when you click back it goes to update_task_name.php instead of dashboard.php

Comment: can u help me to fix this problem?